# Album art for song is not showing correct in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-cursor, android-music-player

Here is my cursor by which I m getting songs from local storage :

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION+">0", null, sortOrder);
```

I m displaying album by using another cursor like this shown below because I m not able to do this using same cursor :

```
ContentResolver musicResolve = getContentResolver();
Uri smusicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;    
Cursor musicCursorTogetAlbum =musicResolve.query(smusicUri,null, null, null, null);
```

I m displaying album like this but it doesn't display correctly :

```
    musicCursorTogetAlbum.moveToFirst();
    musicCursorTogetAlbum.move(cursorPosition);

    int x = musicCursorTogetAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
    int id_albumCursor = musicCursorTogetAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

    String thisArt = musicCursorTogetAlbum.getString(x);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thisArt);
    Bitmap bm_temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thisArt);

    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {  
         iv_album_art.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
```

And `cursorPosition` is the int type variable which gives position of cursor of `cursor` which I m using for getting song from local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to get album art of songs :

`

```
public static Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context, Long album_id){
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    try{
          final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
          Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
          ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
          if (pfd != null){
              FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
              bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
              pfd = null;
              fd = null;
          }
      } catch(Error ee){}
      catch (Exception e) {}
      return bm;
    }
```

`

Comment: You're welcome! :)
Would appreciate if you can mark the answer as useful as well..(^ arrow)